# Wordpress php Only show next post link in same category

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using the next post link function of WP to show next and previous navigation links to the "next post in same category" all good with this...the issue i have is that when I'm in the "last" post of a category, the "NEXT" link appears anyway and doing what i dont want: linking to a different category 1st post. the same with the 1st post of a category, when browsing the first post of a category the "PREVIOUS" link appears linking to previous post of a another different category... I would like that in the 1st and last post, this links aren't shown.

```
   <div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
                        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_linknext_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' .     
        _x( '&#9668; Previous', 'Previous post link','category' ,TRUE ) . '</span>' ); ?></div>
                        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( 'Next &#9658; ', 'Next post link', 'category',TRUE ) . '</span>' ); ?> </div>
                    </div><!-- #nav-above -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test whether there **is** a next or previous post by using the get_previous_post_link and get_next_post_link functions. For example:

```
<div id="nav-above" class="navigation">

    <?php $prev = get_previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' .     
    _x( '&#9668; Previous', 'Previous post link','category' ,TRUE ) . '</span>' ); ?>
    <?php if ($prev) : ?>
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php echo $prev ?></div>
    <? endif; ?>

    <?php $next = get_next_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( 'Next &#9658; ', 'Next post link', 'category',TRUE ) . '</span>' ); ?>
    <?php if ($next) : ?>
     <div class="nav-next"><?php echo $next ?> </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- #nav-above -->
```

Comment: thanks I found the answer in Wordpress stackexchange... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178780/next-and-prev-post-link-only-within-category